# Publishing npm packages offline

Tags: npm, azure-artifacts

I'm running TFS 2018 on-premise, which is offline and has no access to nuget.org.  One of our struggles was to coordinate open-sourced npm packages between the dev team.  With TFS 201 I can now setup an npm feed in Package Management, which may be a solution.  The idea is to get all the npm packages in the feed.

What I've done so far is to retrieve these packages (using *npm install*) on an internet facing box, then transfer them to the offline box (copying over the entire npm-cache folder).  Then I would iterate over all the npm packages and run *npm publish* to my TFS registry.

For **most** packages, this works well.  There are a number of packages with prepublish scripts or likewise that error out.  I can still get them in the registry with --force (*npm publish -f*).  However, I'm not sure this is truly working as I'm unable to install some of these.  I get an ENOENT errno -4058.  One example is the *[acorn](https://www.npmjs.com/package/acorn)* repo.

I'm wondering if there is a better way to go about this? Possibly there is a bulk upload option for these packages.

Comment: Do you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question here as the only other proposed answer did not address the idea to get the packages into the TFS Packages feed **and** remain offline.

Publishing npm tarballs (.tgz) to the TFS npm package repository worked without fail.  Whereas before, I was trying to publish using the package I had in my cache.  I found a particular npm package ([npm-package-downloader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-package-downloader)) which allowed me to download the necessary npm packages and their dependencies.  I then transferred these tarballs to the offline tfs box and published them using `npm publish <package>`.

The full workflow was:

1. (Internet accessible box) `npm install -global npm-package-downloader`
2. (Internet accessible box) `npmDownload -d -e -a -o "<path>" -p "pkg1 pkg2 etc"`
3. (Internet accessible box) Zip  from #2 (even though there is a zip option for npmDownload, this always broke)
4. (Internet accessible box) Transfer zip to offline box
5. (Offline box) Unzip files
6. (Offline box) `npm set registry <tfs registry>`
7. (Offline box) For each .tgz `npm publish <pkg.tgz>`.  Note, I used powershell to do this for me.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can setup a build agent that can access internet, the TFS can be intranet accessible.

Secondly, you may try to [change default npm-cache directory](https://blog.jsinh.in/change-default-nodejs-npm-and-npm-cache-directory-on-windows/#.WvKzIIiFOUk) that contains necessary packages, then install the packages through [npm-cache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-cache).

On the other hand, you may include the packages to source control.

Comment: For #1, box was to remain offline, so this doesn't work.  For #2, this won't utilize TFS's packages and allow others to download, so this won't work.  For #3, this is considered bad practice and it doesn't solve the issue for getting them into TFS